# C# Shorthand Property Question

Tags: c#, properties

So here is a bit of syntax that I have never seen before, can someone tell me what this means?  Not sure if this is supposed to be some shorthand for an abstract property declaration or something or what.

```
public Class1 myVar { get; set; }
```

For what its worth, Class1 is an abstract class.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

In C# 3.0 and later, [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) make property-declaration more concise when no additional logic is required in the property accessors. They also enable client code to create objects When you declare a property as shown in the following example, the compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field that can only be accessed through the property's get and set accessors.

```
// Auto-Impl Properties for trivial get and set
    public double TotalPurchases { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
```

Comment: I'd vote you up for having a more thorough explanation but I am all out for the day.

Answer (score 29):

This is the syntax to let the compiler create a (hidden) field for you.

Also very useful is:

```
public Class1 myVar{ get; private set; }
```

Comment: `protected` works just, too. Just like `private`. I'm fairly certain you can set accessibility for `get`, too, but I haven't ever tried.

Comment: +1 this is exactly for what I was searching for. I wanted something to include in shorthand so `set` operation can be done only by the class member functions. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 25):

It may look like an abstract property or a property from an interface but it is far from it.  In order to encourage developers to use properties (as they are a best-practice for many reasons) Microsoft decided to include this feature in C# 3 to allow you to declare properties with greater ease.

Here is the standard way of creating a property:

```
String foo;

public String Foo
{
    get { return this.foo }
    set { this.foo = value; }
}
```

Now this requires quite a bit of typing and as developers are lazy to the core sometimes we are tempted to create public fields just to save some time.

Now with the C# 3 compiler we can do this:

```
public String Foo { get; set; }
```

While this looks a bit strange, consider the work that the compiler is doing on your behalf.  The previous code gets compiled to this:

```
[CompilerGenerated]    
private string <Foo>k__BackingField;

public string Foo
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    get
    {
        return this.<Foo>k__BackingField;
    }
    [CompilerGenerated]
    set
    {
        this.<Foo>k__BackingField = value;
    }
}
```

So even though the syntax looks a bit strange you are still creating a property exactly the way you are used to.

Answer (score 8):

It is shorthand for a property that does nothing more that storing the value in a field. So it would be equivalent to:

```
private Class1 _myVar;

public Class1 myVar
{
  get{ return _myVar; }
  set{ _myVar = value;}
}
```

Its just a simple property that yoy could replace with a more complex evantuation at a later time without changing the interface.

Answer (score 7):

It's called an automatic or [auto-implemented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) property, and it's not abstract.  You can use that property as-is.  The compiler will create a backing store for it behind the scenes.

It's very much like just using a field instead of a property, but you get property semantics and you can use it for things like databinding that require properties.

Comment: And you can later change to an explicit implementation without changing your interface to your callers.

Answer (score 2):

These are Auto-Implemented properties.  They allow you to make you code more concise.  You can read more about them here:

[Auto-Implement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

You can also make the accessors have different access levels:

public int MyVar { get; private set; }

This allows you to expose the property external to the class and still set it internally.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic getters and setters.